# Retrieving List<String> from List<Object> containing List<String> with java stream

Tags: java, java-8

I have this situation:

```
Class Employee{
//some attributes
List<String> idContract

//getter, setter
}
```

And I need to retrieve a List idContracts from a list using java 8 stream.

I was trying something like that:

```
lst.stream().filter(o->!o.getLstDipFuoriSoglia().isEmpty())
      .map(ResultOdg::getLstDipFuoriSoglia)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but that, of course, returns a List< List < String >>, so how can I achieve that goal?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Use `flatMap`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: Just need to change map to flatMap? Nothing else?

Comment: Leave the `.map` as it is, and add `.flatMap(List::stream)`.

Comment: What is `getLstDipFuoriSoglia` in the code? Is `lst` a `List<Employee>`? How is `ResultOdg` defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `flatMap` operation for converting `List` to `Stream`

```
lst.stream().filter(o->!o.getLstDipFuoriSoglia().isEmpty)
            .map(ResultOdg::getLstDipFuoriSoglia)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you can have one `flatMap` operation

```
lst.stream().filter(o->!o.getLstDipFuoriSoglia().isEmpty)
            .flatMap(list->list.getLstDipFuoriSoglia().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```